# Unable to return using post method in an html form. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to programming, i have been learning django for the first time. I created a form using home.html file an i requested using POST method, but in the error it is giving the request method as GET. When I remove the method="POST" and put request.GET in views file, it is working fine. What am I doing wrong here?

home.html

```
< form action="add" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

views.py

```
def add(request):

    val1= int(request.POST['num1'])
    val2= int(request.POST['num2'])
    res= val1 +val2

    return render(request, 'result.html' ,{'result': res})
```

I am getting the following error:
MultiValueDictKeyError at /add
'num1'
**Request Method:   GET**
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add?num1=17&num2=4
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'num1'

Comment: The `add()` view is trying to access `request.POST` even when the request is a `GET`.

Comment: yes how can i change the request to GET. Or why is it not changing even when i have mentioned method="POST"

Comment: Show us the `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

**Views.py**

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #LOGIC AS TO WHAT TO SERVE WHEN THIS VIEW RECIEVES A POST REQUEST
        val1= int(request.POST.get('num1'))
        val2= int(request.POST.get('num2'))
        res= val1 +val2
        return render(request, 'result.html' ,{'result': res})

    else:
        #serves non POST request , ie GET in this case
        ...your GET REQUEST LOGIC
        return render(request, 'GETREQUESTPAGE.html' ,{'param1': paramval})
```

**urls.py:**

```
# blog.urls
from django.urls import path

from . import views
#example consider a url for app named blog... mention the app name in the urls.py as below
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index(), name='add'),
]
```

**home.html :**
if you want to the view called "**add**" in the app blog to handle the **POST** request, then ...

```
< form action="{% url blogs.add %}" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```